# DAX measure vs calculated column

Tags: dax

```
PMF2 = NORM.DIST((ALL(Final_TAT_DIST[FinalTAT]),
[Measure1],STDEVX.P(Final_TAT_DIST,Final_TAT_DIST[FinalTAT]),FALSE)
```

measure 1 is mean of column. Trying to calculate prob mass function of every TAT value in a column as a measure. Managed to do it as a calculated column, but the above doesnt work. When visualising the error is "expecting single value but table of values provided.

Any ideas?

Comment: I need more info, could you post a snippet of your data?

Comment: "NORM.DIST" Needs the first value to be an number not a table. I will see if I can find a work around.